# Invoke or call more than one method at same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to call more than one method at same time in my page load in asp.net??
i have 4 methods to called in my page load event.
but i want to call all 4 methods and not wait for 1st method to get finish then call 2nd method.

How to achieve this is in asp.net 4.0?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, You can't call all the 4 methods at a time there must be at least one second delay. If you still want to call the 4 methods then as Davide Piras told you use the multithreading and take the help of "BackgroundWorker" class beacause for return value you need to wait until and unless all the 4 methods execute.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain - what has "one second" to do with anything? And IMO BackgroundWorker is a poor choice on the web tier

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[]
{
   new Task(Method0),
   new Task(Method1),
   new Task(Method2),
   new Task(Method3)
}

foreach(var task in tasks)
   task.Start();
```

Or more shortly

```
new Task(Method0).Start();
new Task(Method1).Start();
new Task(Method2).Start();
new Task(Method3).Start();
```

Comment: also, `new[] {new Task(Method0),...,new Task(MethodN)}` should work

Answer (score 14):

First off, it is important to know if what you are doing is sensible. If they are all CPU-bound, then ***do not*** do this, IMO; a web server is already highly threaded, and is usually a busy place to begin with. Chances are high that you will slow the whole thing down by using multiple cores. It'll look great for 1 user, though!

If you are IO-bound, then there are *any number* of ways to do this; the preferred would be to use the inbuilt async methods of whatever you are talking to, so you can use IOCP rather than regular threads. So for a `NetworkStream`, you would use `BeginRead(...)` etc.

Then you need to join everything together. Lots more ways; personally I tend to use `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse`, as this avoids going to unmanaged code (many wait-handles are actually OS-provided).

Also note: threading/parallelism comes in a bundle alongside many fun ways to fail; normally you only need to worry overly about *static* methods/data for synchronization, but if you have multiple threads *in a single request* doing things: watch out for bumps... there are many.

The next version of .NET is meant to make continuations a lot easier; I need to take a look to see how easily we can apply the current experimental code to IOCP scenarios.

Comment: Nice Marc, this is definitely the way to answer a question like this as it gives a bit more guidance rather than just answering the question.

Comment: "A web server is already highly threaded" - this line made me avoid multiple calls for my application. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is make asynchronous method calls.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you make your methods asynchronous it would work.

(basic stub):

```
method1(onReadyCallback1);
method2(onReadyCallback2);

private void onReadyCallback1() {

}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) and then [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx) for an example

from the MSDN documentation

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
public class Example {
    public static void Main() {
        // Queue the task.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc));

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread does some work, then sleeps.");
        // If you comment out the Sleep, the main thread exits before
        // the thread pool task runs.  The thread pool uses background
        // threads, which do not keep the application running.  (This
        // is a simple example of a race condition.)
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits.");
    }

    // This thread procedure performs the task.
    static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo) {
        // No state object was passed to QueueUserWorkItem, so 
        // stateInfo is null.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from the thread pool.");
    }
}
```