# Jquery Error-Object Doesn't support this method or property

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am using asp.net 4.0. i am creating the Url with the help of "routes.MapPageRoute".

so i noticed that jquery file was not gettin loaded due to url not being static. so i used
"ResolveClientUrl". I could load the js files but in jquery code i get error.

I did ask this same question on 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1680184.aspx/1?Jquery+Error+Object+Doesn+t+support+this+method+or+property+

I have given the image for the error also..
please anyone can guide me where am i going wrong.

I somehow feel that i have issue due to the pattern i am writting url in global file.

Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link href="../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fancyYoutube").fancybox({
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'fade',
                'width': 680,
                'height': 495,
                'type': 'swf'
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Please post all the relevant content and code here instead of referencing to an external forum, for legacy purposes ;)

Comment: I have added it myself from the other place.. @Abhishek please update if you have different code (as suggested by Majid) now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `$.noConflict();` from the beginning of code; or if you want to keep it, you should not use `$` in the lines following it:

Solution 1:

```
// $.noConflict(); <-- comment or remove this line
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".fancyYoutube").fancybox({
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'fade',
    'width': 680,
    'height': 495,
    'type': 'swf'
  });
});
```

Solution 2:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".fancyYoutube").fancybox({
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'fade',
    'width': 680,
    'height': 495,
    'type': 'swf'
  });
});
```

Explanation:
As [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) say, you use `$.noConflict()` to tell jQuery *do not use `$` and let other libraries use it*. Here you have no other library, so you don't need to *relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable*, so both solutions should work for you.

Comment: ya i have not posted the code. it was giving me error so only i have removed the code of that page.

Comment: So what remains to check? *'Here used to be buggy code which I removed, could you tell me what was wrong with it?'*?

Comment: ok.. Now i uploaded the page with code.. :-) i had just removed the code as that part was not working. Now can you please guide me?

Comment: That did solve the problem. but now i am getting error in fancybox js file. The error is

    _show = function() {
   var pos, equal;

   loading.hide();

   if (wrap.is(":visible") && false === currentOpts.onCleanup(currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts)) {
    $.event.trigger('fancybox-cancel');

    busy = false;
    return;
   }

in the line if(wrap.is....
same error as object not supported.
what could be reason for this error...it is same js file which works fine with other page.

Comment: @shadow: that solved the problem but i am getting error in js file now

Comment: @Abhishek you mean different error? So Edit your original question and give the full details: exact code you're using now and the exact error message.

Comment: Solved my full issue now. now the issue was my css file which was getting loaded due reference... Thanks a lot Majid :-) and shadow you too for editing my post. i had to increase the reference level.  <link href="../../../js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @Majid. I have marked all most all answer expect the MBA question and calling different method at same time.

Comment: @Abhishek, excellent, and good luck ;) It is your question, an thus your right to judge if any of the answers are right, but it seems you are neglecting [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298315/invoke-or-call-more-then-one-method-at-same-time). Please note that if you ask about some possibility, and the answers provide reason, why what you want is not possible, that *is* the answer nonetheless.

Comment: This worked great for me in a similar situation.  We spent 1/2 the morning trying find a fix and putting the $.noConflict before the .docReady did it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

check out that in css file all src path are correct:

for example, this line has a src worng with regard to my web tree:

```
.fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-n { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='**fancybox/**fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }
```

Also check that css file is loading correctly. Use the debug option in your browser you check it out.